# Problema con el paquete setup de Python

Tags: python, pip

Tengo un problema ya que recientemente desinstale una versión antigua de Python e instalé la última 3.11 y me tira este error cuando quiero instalar pygame, no sé si tengo que instalar un paquete extra de setups ya que al ingresar el comando pip list solo tengo los paquetes pip, setuptools y ez-setup

````
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
     
     
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration... ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que este problema viene porque pygame-2.1.2 todavía no está disponible para Python 3.11

La solución temporal para esto es `pip install pygame --pre` para que puedas instalarlo, al incluir el parámetro `--pre` en pip puedes instalar la versión en desarrollo para poder utilizarla con Python 3.11.

Comment: Aquí hay dos preguntas relacionadas de la versión en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311396/pygame-no-setup-file-exists-running-buildconfig-config-py https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238684/how-do-i-install-pygame-on-python-3-11-0-its-showing-the-following-error que utilizan la misma solución.

Comment: Genial, me solucionó el problema. Gracias.